# WCF Operation is null when I have Parallel Process

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have an UserContext that in each WCF call I fill it and in Castle container its lifestyle is PerWcfOperation

```
public class IUserContext
{
    string UserName {get;}
    string Token {get;}
}

Container.Register(Component.For<IUserContext>().ImplementedBy<UserContext>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation());
```

In service method when I resolve IUserContext its null.

```
public void Foo()
{
    foreach(...) {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>method1);
    }

    void method1()
    {
         // context is null
         var context = Container.Resolve<IUserContext>();
    }
}
```

Which LifeStyle I must use that share in all threads that open in WCF Call?
Or Is there any way that sharded IUserContext between all tasks?

Comment: is the context stored on the thread?

Comment: @TMcKeown yes Context stored in thread

Comment: so can't you set it and then clear it in the task execution?

Comment: @TMcKeown yes in task execution  the context is null

Comment: you can set it can't you?  Get the context before creating the task and then in the task set it on the running thread.  then clear it..

Comment: @TMcKeown in wcf start request I set the context but in task execution the context is null and in main process in Foo method I can access to the context